# Xubuntu 16.04 optimus can't disable panning and windows maximize across both monitors

Tags: nvidia, xubuntu, multiple-monitors, nvidia-optimus

I have following setup:

- nvidia optimus laptop (Thinkpad P50), using proprietary nvidia driver
- 2 screens

  - external 1920x1080 screen connected to nvidia card (DP-3.2 in xrandr), it is positioned left of my 2nd screen
  - internal 1920x1080 screen connected to integrated intel card (right of 1st screen)
    nvidia drivers 367.35-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.2
- kernel 4.6.6 (from http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.6.6/)

When I boot lightdm sets the screens to clone, which is fine.

After login, or when I connect the external screen and use "Displays" utility to extend the desktop to the monitor, following happens

- external screen to the second screen (the screen "scrolls" when I position the mouse cursor to the right edge) - I had the same issue on 15.10, but it was the only one, I am able to work around this by playing with "Display" utitily (changing orientation, turning screen off etc. could not find a deterministic way to do this)
- maximized windows span both screens
- new windows appear in the centre of the whole desktop, not current monitor (= half on first screen, half on second screen)

**None of this happens when I move the internal screen left of the external screen.**

My xorg.conf: http://pastebin.com/UmAcNVSy

xrandr -q output: http://pastebin.com/SLJNpZTm

xorg.log: http://pastebin.com/J07AT5yq

Comment: The same issue reported on xfce forums: https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=14307

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems it was a bug in nvidia driver fixed in 375.10:

> Fixed a bug that caused issues with panning and cursor constraining when mixing PRIME-driven displays with natively driven displays.

from https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/972585

Installing nvidia drivers version 375.20 (first stable version with the fix above) from ubuntu ["graphics drivers" team](https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) ppa

resolved the issue.